# How to validate user data from .txt file? C++

Tags: c++

im trying to validate user name, mail and password from "users.txt" file, im trying to use fgets, but when I ran it, it wouldnt recognize the information and, when I tried printing what it was actually validating, turned out that the strings it got from the fgets function were totally unexpected.

Data from users.txt:

- jean
- jn@gmail.com
- jj123
- alfredo
- alf@gmail.com
- somepass
- robt
- rob@gmail.com
- rob111

As far as I know, fgets returns the string until it finds a \n character or it reaches the end of the file.
what I actually got from printf:

jj123
jj123
jj123
robt
robt
robt
rob111
(null)
(null)

Code:
`

```
void login(bool is_logged_in)
{
    printf("enter your name\n");
    string name_session = GetString();

    printf("enter your mail:\n");
    string mail_session = GetString();

    printf("enter your password:\n");
    string password_session = GetString();

    FILE *users_file;
    char getstring[100];
    users_file = fopen("users.txt", "r");
    if (users_file != NULL)
    {
        while (feof(users_file) == 0)
        {
            //added this to check what I was actually getting from file
            string text1 = fgets(getstring,100,users_file);
            string text2 = fgets(getstring,100,users_file);
            string text3 = fgets(getstring,100,users_file);
            printf("%s",text1);
            printf("%s",text2);
            printf("%s",text3);
            //3 times because the if statement is checking 3 strings

            if ((fgets(getstring,100,users_file) == name_session ) &&
                (fgets(getstring,100,users_file) == mail_session) &&
                (fgets(getstring,100,users_file) == password_session))
            {
                is_logged_in = true;
                fclose(users_file);
                menu();
            }
        }
        printf("You've failed your log in.\n");
        fclose(users_file);
        menu();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("¡¡ERROR!!: there's been a problem and the program will now exit.\n");
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Your code is more C than C++. What is `string`? Are you `using std;`?

Comment: Use C++ file streams ([`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)-s) and [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: these are my libraries: #include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

Comment: Also, compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and **use the debugger `gdb`**

Comment: If you're going to use `fgets` you should use it correctly.  If you pass the same first parameter 3 times you're overwriting the first 2 strings. If `string` is a typedef for `char*` then your comparisons aren't going to work either.

Comment: So you are following a course on C programming, and you code in C++. I recommend using the right language and the right compiler (and debugger). C and C++ are different languages, choose one! If coding in C, compile with a C (not C++) compiler, e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` and **use the debugger**

Comment: You may have more success here: https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ I'd guess they're more familiar with the provided headers and such.

Comment: To compare C strings use [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), not `==` (which compare *addresses*)

Comment: `while (feof(users_file) == 0)` checks for end of file before reading from the file. More on why that's bad here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong . None of the file accesses  test for success, yet the values are used anyway. It's easier to find errors when you have the code actively looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

Use fstream instead

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
   string line;
   ifstream file("users.txt");
   if(!file){
     cout<<"file do not exist!\n";
     return 0;
   }
   while(getline(file,line)){
     cout<<line<<endl;
   }
}
```